# Cookies are set in local devlopment but not in production

Tags: reactjs, cookies, axios, nestjs, railway

I'm using React frontend hosted on netlify(swiftreseller.netlify.app) , NestJS on the backend. While working on localhost, I was able to set cookies in backend response when logging in. But when I hosted the backed on railway(swiftreseller-api.up.railway.app), I could not perform this operation. I tried using the api on my frontend locally (localhost:3000), still gives me the same issues

login endpoint from swiftreseller.netlify.app

```
  @Post('login')
  async login(
    @Body('email') email: string,
    @Body('password') password: string,
    @Res({ passthrough: true }) response: Response,
  ) {
    const user = await this.userService.findOne({ email }, ['role']);

    if (!user) {
      throw new NotFoundException('User not found');
    }
    if (!(await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password))) {
      throw new BadRequestException('Invalid credentials');
    }

    const jwt = await this.jwtService.signAsync({ id: user.id });

    response.cookie('jwt', jwt, {
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: 'none',
      secure: true,
      domain: '.swiftreseller.netlify.app',
    });

    return user;
  }
```

login endpoint localhost:3000

```
  @Post('login')
  async login(
    @Body('email') email: string,
    @Body('password') password: string,
    @Res({ passthrough: true }) response: Response,
  ) {
    const user = await this.userService.findOne({ email }, ['role']);

    if (!user) {
      throw new NotFoundException('User not found');
    }
    if (!(await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password))) {
      throw new BadRequestException('Invalid credentials');
    }

    const jwt = await this.jwtService.signAsync({ id: user.id });

    response.cookie('jwt', jwt, {
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: 'none',
      secure: true,
      domain: 'localhost',
    });

    return user;
  }
```

nest js main.ts file (swiftreseller.netlify.app)

```
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as cors from 'cors';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.setGlobalPrefix('api');
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  app.use(cookieParser());

 
  app.enableCors({
   origin: 'https://swiftreseller.netlify.app',
   credentials: true,
  });
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

nest js main.ts file (swiftreseller.netlify.app)

```
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as cors from 'cors';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.setGlobalPrefix('api');
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  app.use(cookieParser());

 
  app.enableCors({
   origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
   credentials: true,
  });
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

frontend code using axios

```
 const url = "https://swiftreseller-api.up.railway.app/api/login";

  const config = {
    withCredentials: true, // enable sending cookies
  };

  // submit
  const onSubmit = async (values) => {
    console.log("Form data", values);
   
    axios
      .post(url, values, config)
      .then((response) => {
        
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```